# Is indirection always a size/performance hit in antlr grammars?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

In some various testing I've done over the weeks, it seems the more 'compact' a grammar is the faster it runs and the smaller the program size -- and anything possible that can  reduce various downstream rule/function calls (while keeping the grammar valid) is a good thing to do.

Here is the most basic example I could come up with demonstrating this:

```
grammar NoIndirection;
root: (expr ';')* EOF;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'
    | '-' expr
    | '+' expr
    | Atom
    ;

Atom:
    [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ | '\'' Atom '\''
    ;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

```
grammar YesIndirection1;
root: (expr ';')* EOF;

expr
    : parenExpr
    | uExpr
    | atomExpr
    ;

parenExpr: '(' expr ')';
uExpr: ('+'|'-') expr;
atomExpr: Atom;

Atom:
    [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ | '\'' Atom '\''
    ;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

```
grammar YesIndirection2;
root: (expr ';')* EOF;

expr
    : parenExpr
    | uExpr
    | atomExpr
    ;

parenExpr: '(' expr ')';
uExpr: uExprP | uExprM;
uExprP: '+' expr;
uExprM: '-' expr;
atomExpr: Atom;

Atom:
    [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ | '\'' Atom '\''
    ;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

The timings and output program size on a ~1MB file are as follows:

The timings and size on a ~1MB file are as follows:

1. 0m0.476s /  72K
2. 0m0.578s / 88K
3. 0m0.636s / 104K (~1.4x on both performance and size over the first)

My question(s) related to this are as follows:

- Does the above seem valid in your experience -- that is, the less number of rules/indirection there is, the faster the parser is?
- Why is this the case that function calls should be so expensive?
- Finally, given that indirection is (always) a performance hit, would it be a good idea to write the rules for maximum readability and then preprocess the file so that as much as possible is in-lined?

Comment: You don't seem to have tried `expr: ('-'|'+')* Atom | '(' expr ')'`. But that might not give you as useful a parse tree. Anyway, and I think someone already said this in one of these questions, your first criterion shouldn't be the speed of the parse, but rather the ease of use of the parse tree, since you're going to have to do that after the parse. And your second criterion should likely be the readability of the grammar. At some point you might have to worry about performance, but unless your parser is really inefficient, parse speed is unlikely to dominate the complete application.

Comment: @rici how were you able to refactor it to just two alternates? The best I can see is with three: `expr: ('-'|'+') expr | Atom | '(' expr ')'`. How were you able to combine the first two?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was typing to fast. `expr: ('-'|'+')* atom; atom: Atom | '(' expr ')'`.

Comment: @rici yea they run about the same speed, probably since the first token differentiates it with the `+`, `-` so it doesn't really need to backtrack.

Comment: Depending on the rest of your grammar, it doesn't need to backtrack at all; every alternative starts with a unique token. But that has to be counterbalanced against the cost of the additional indirection in `atom:` (which could, of course, be avoided by direct substitution, but that sort of manic single-line-ism is usually counter-productive in readability).

Comment: @rici yea I was thinking of, if the performance is too poor when all is said-and-done, to try and pre-process is to make those single-line-isms at runtime.

Comment: Certainly a possibility. Some parser generators know how to optimize unit reductions, but I don't think Antlr is one of them. (But, as I said, profile the whole application first. "Premature optimisation..." and all that. It's highly likely that the extra overhead in parsing is just noise.)

Comment: re: performance, the usual guidance re: premature optimization applies here as well as anywhere else.  Don't make things obtuse chasing maximum performance until you know that your performance is an issue.